# Azure IoT Edge Module: Docker Container Run Time Options in VS Code Deployment Template

Tags: azure-iot-edge

Need to deploy a docker container "sample/api:v1" with docker runtime options such as --gpus=all and -e DATABASE=NO as an azure IoT edge module. How to specify these docker runtime options in VS Code- deployment.template.json

docker run -dt --gpus=all -e DATABASE=NO -p 5656:5656 sample/api:v1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably what you're looking for, you need to specify this as the createOptions of your module in the deployment JSON:

```json
{
   "ENV":[
      "DATABASE=NO"
   ],
   "HostConfig":{
      "DeviceRequests":[
         {
            "Driver":"",
            "Count":-1,
            "DeviceIDs":null,
            "Capabilities":[
               [
                  "gpu"
               ]
            ],
            "Options":{
               
            }
         }
      ],
      "PortBindings":{
         "5656/tcp":[
            {
               "HostPort":"5656"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

In `ENV` you'll find your environment variable. Under `PortBindings` you can specify what ports need to be open.

Under `DeviceRequests` you'll find the create options equivalent of `--gpus=all`. Support for this in Azure IoT Edge is from 1.0.10, so make sure to update you edge runtime. Check [here](https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/issues/1580) and [here](https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/issues/3183) for GitHub issues where others have done the same.